# Powershell Output File column too narrow

Tags: powershell

I am trying to list current installed applications and the DisplayVersion keeps getting its column shortened when I want it to show as normal on one line. It runs fine when running the code in a PS session but when running from a ps1 script file, the output for DisplayVersion is 1 character wide with NewLines for each integer.

```
$FormatEnumerationLimit = -1

Get-ItemProperty HKLM:\Software\Wow6432Node\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall\* | 
  Select-Object Publisher, DisplayName, DisplayVersion |
    Where {$_.DisplayName} | 
      Sort-Object -Property Publisher,DisplayName,DisplayVersion | 
        Format-Table -AutoSize -Wrap > $FullFileName
```

Comment: your code works for me. the `DisplayVersion` column in the file has each version on a single line as `1.2.3.4` as expected. //// win7x64, ps5.1

Comment: With my default console width of 132 chars here it displays ok, instead of `Format-Table` try `| Out-File $FullFileName -Width 300 -Encoding Ascii` or whatever encoding suits you.

Answer (score 0):

Considering the exact suggestion from **LotPings**, I am making this as an answer because it makes more sense to dump it in File using `out-file` & use `Encoding` instead of redirection.

Replace this:

```
Format-Table -AutoSize -Wrap > $FullFileName
```

To:

```
Out-File $FullFileName -Width 300 -Encoding Ascii
```

Comment: I am still getting the same results where Publisher and DisplayName are fine, but DisplayVersion gets broken out into 14 lines (one for each character) for the header and the same for the subsequent rows. On a Windows 10 PC PS 5.1.17134.590